# How to set a Text in the TextView of the second fragment by pushing on the button

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I have 1 activity with 2 fragments in an Android app.
On the first fragment, I did put a button (btnA).
On the second I putt a TextView (txtB).

How can I set a Text in the TextView of the second fragment by pushing on the button on the first activity?

Thx, I'm new to android app development

JoskXP

Comment: read here about fragments http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Read there, example post is exactly what you asked ! [Using Fragments in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well you could do something like this:

In your activity, provide public links to both of your fragments:

```
public FragmentNumberOne getFragmentOne() {
    return fragOne;
}

public FragmentNumberTwo getFragmentTwo() {
    return fragTwo;
}
```

then provide accessors to the `TextView` in the `Fragment` class of fragment one:

```
public TextView getTextView() {
    return mTextView;
}
```

and in your original `Fragment` you can then use:

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).getFragmentOne().getTextView().setText("Hello");
```

Comment: You should read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: That's just typical Android team trying to make something more complicated than it needs to be :P above example works in exactly the same way but you can read exactly what it's doing at a glance.

Comment: It might be a bit more complex but with your method you have tighly coupled FragmentNumberOne with FragmentNumberTwo. You cannot use one without the other

Comment: It's only as tightly coupled as required (A using B requires A and B). Where as in the example in the link, you need to describe each function for each possible fragment (Fragments A, B, C, D, E AND each of their function sets, 1, 2, 3 would give A1, A2, A3, B1, B2 etc).

Comment: You can use public method on your fragment **from your activity**. What you need to describe are the **events** your fragment can generate (for example `onButtonClick`). Ideally there should be no direct communication between fragments, the activity should be the dispatcher

Comment: The way in the link directs you to: `FragmentA -> Activity -> FragmentB` (There is no thread switching, the `Activity` contains code to call the `FragmentB` directly). The way in my answer directs you to `FragmentA -> Activity -> FragmentB` (No thread switching, The Activity returns a reference to the Fragment on which the code can be called). In my example, each `Fragment` is responsible for it's method working no matter where it's called, In the links example the `Activity` and `Fragment` share responsibility which becomes a nightmare to maintain across several Activies using the `Fragment`.

Comment: Seems to me Polymorphism via action (Activity can `sortViews()`, `showEmailForm()`, `disableButtons()` through whatever Fragment it happens to have) and Polymorphism via Fragment (Activity has a `decendent of SearchResultFragment`, `decendent of EmailFragment`) is preference and situational specific.

Answer (score 2):

Following Android best practice described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

This is slightly more verbose than the solution of Graeme, but allow reuse of your fragments. 
(You could use FragmentWithButton in another screen, and the button could do something different)

You have two Fragments (`FragmentWithButton` and `FragmentWithText`) and one activity (`MyActivity`)

1. Create an **interface** `FragmentWithButtonHost` in `FragmentWithButton`:

   ```
   public class FragmentWithButton extends Fragment {

       FragmentWithButtonHost host;

       public interface FragmentWithButtonHost{
           public void onMyButtonClicked(View v);
       }

       @Override
       public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
           super.onAttach(activity);

           try {
               host = (FragmentWithButtonHost) activity;
           }
           catch (ClassCastException e) {
               // TODO Handle exception
           }
       }

       /**
        * Click handler for MyButton
        */
       public void onMyButtonClick(View v) {
           host.onMyButtonClicked(v);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a **public** method in `FragmentWithText` to set the text from the activity:

   ```
   public class FragmentWithText extends Fragment{

         ...

         public void setText(String text) {
              // Set text displayed on the fragment
         }
   }
   ```
3. Make sure your activity implements the `FragmentWithButtonHost` interface, and call the `setText` method:

   ```
   public MyActivity implements FragmentWithButtonHost {

       ...

       @Override
       public void onMyButtonClicked(View v) {
           getFragmentWithText().setText("TEST");
       }

       public FragmentWithText getFragmentWithText() {
           // Helper method to get current instance of FragmentWithText, 
           // or create a new one if there isn't any
       }
   }
   ```