# Android nested fragment-fragment interactions

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Android best practices for fragment-fragment interaction (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14708666/1290264) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)) forces the `Activity` to implement a listener defined by the child fragment. The `Activity` then manages the communication between fragments.

From my understanding this is to keep the fragments loosely coupled from each other. However,

1. **Is this also the case for nested fragments?** I can imagine it might make sense for a nested fragment to report directly to it's parent fragment instead of the Activity.
2. If a nested fragment has its parent fragment implement it's listener, how would one (or should one) require the parent fragment to do this. In other words, is a similar to the paradigm to the following but for `Fragments`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);

       try {
           mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
           throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                   + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you define an interface in the fragment, you can have the parent activity or parent fragment implementing it. There is no rule that says fragment should not implement interface of a child fragment. One example where this make sense is that fragment A has two children Fragments B, C. A implements B's interface, when A gets a call back, it might need to update fragment C. Exactly the same thing with activity, just different level.

Comment: however, the way described in the google link posted in the question encourages/enforces it to be an `Activity` by attaching the listener using the fragment's `onAttach()` and throwing an error if not.

Comment: The doc encourage that fragment shouldn't communicate with another fragment directly. Not that it has to be an Activity.

Comment: Is there a particular reason Google suggests to throw an `Exception` if the listener is not implemented by the `Activity`. Should I just remove that code?

Comment: That's because the main purpose of doing this is for inter-fragment communication, if the activity do not implement the interface, the fragment by itself is not useful at all in those cases. So you might need to tell the activity that "wait, you forget to implement the interface i defined"

Comment: Regarding your second question, you could call getParentFragment from the child fragment, and do instanceof to see if that implements the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems like enforcing a listener makes it easier to attach the listener without calling a `setListener(...)` but it also pigeon-holes the Fragment to only be used with `Activity`s or `Fragment`s but not both. It might be best to just do away with it altogether.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone wanted an example of an implementation that ensures parent context implements the callbacks while not caring whether it is an activity or fragment, the following worked for me:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Callbacks) {
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) context;
    } else {
        if (getParentFragment() != null && getParentFragment() instanceof Callbacks) {
            mCallbacks = (Callbacks) getParentFragment();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement " + TAG + ".Callbacks");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the same pattern for child/parent interactions using [getParentFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment()). The parent fragment refers to whichever fragment has this one added through its ChildFragmentManager. If this Fragment is attached directly to an Activity, this method returns null.